# Gradle refresh failed due to error in downloading dependies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I upgraded android studio to v2.3 and then while trying to update the support repositories, I lost internet connection and I can't understand what to do.

I get the following error in Messages box

```
Gradle 'Pets' project refresh failed
Error:Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
```

On one site it said to delete the file in `.gradle/cache` but I couldn't understand what to delete. I've tried clicking on the link to re-download dependencies but I get the same message.

Could anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: check if your system is connected to internet or not

Comment: You should have an internet connection to download dependencies as it said **Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)**

Comment: make gradle offline! go to Settings>Built>gradle>Offline work

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/Restart try this, internet connection should be there for sync gradle

Comment: My system is connected to the internet and clicking on Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) doesn't work. I also tried File->Invalidate caches/restart but I got the same message. I also removed the cache folder under .gradle but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manually downloading the zipped file from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip  and then replacing the automatically downloaded zipped file in .gradle with it. Then I started Android Studio and it automatically downloaded and installed the required components.